# Acceder a id de elemento HTML con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, eventos, atributos

Estoy haciendo un script que referencio desde dos páginas, ese script se encarga de mostrar un modal de acuerdo a la página que lo llama.
Se requiere que se muestre el modal de acuerdo al id del elemento que lo llama (con un evento), para ello agrego una clase y un id a los elementos.

```
<button class="btn" id="btn1">Click</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn2">Click 2</button>
```

El script contiene lo siguiente:

```
function showModal(){
    if(this.id == "btn1"){
        //mostrar modal
    }
    else if(this.id == "btn2"){
        //mostrar modal
    }
}

buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

for(int i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        showModal();
    });
}
```

Es posible que uno de los dos botones no se encuentre en el documento HTML, se hace así para reutilizar el código en un futuro.
**Nota**: al hacer `console.log(this.id)` arroja `undefined`

Comment: Donde pones `int i=0` debes poner `let i=0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casi lo tenías.

En tu caso, puedes manejar mejor el evento `click`. Y si pasas una referencia de tu función, el `this` estará referenciando el botón clickeado.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
function showModal(){
    if(this.id == "btn1"){
        //mostrar modal
        alert("Click en el boton 1");
    }
    else if(this.id == "btn2"){
        //mostrar modal
        alert("Click en el boton 2");
    }
}

buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

for(let i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', showModal);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="btn1">Click</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn2">Click 2</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de realizar el cometido, te comparto una que va con el código que vas realizando, donde como parámetro mandas el mismo componente que lo llama:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btnUno" onclick="showModal(this)">Botón Uno</button>
        <button id="btnDos" onclick="showModal(this)">Botón Dos</button>

        <script>
            function showModal(boton){
                if(boton.id == "btnUno"){
                    //Muestra modal uno
                }
                else if(boton.id == "btnDos"){
                    //muestra modal dos
                }
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```